# Synthetic division: MathJax

Tags: mathjax

The synthetic division operator is looks like a floor symbol. But it is not exactly floor symbol.  I tried a lot to  find out the synthetic division operator using detexify. But I didn't find out it. How can I write synthetic division using MathJax?

Comment: I think it would make sense to migrate this question to [tex.stackexchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this website: https://mathhelpboards.com/threads/synthetic-and-polynomial-long-division.10218/

It says that you can use this code:

```
\begin{array}{c|rrr}&1&2&1\\-1&&-1&-1\\\hline\\&1&1&0\\\end{array}
```

And I'm sure you can find a way to replace the numbers to fit your liking.

Comment: If we can put divisor on 1st row of array, it will look great. But it is the only possible way to do that. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Prettier rendering:

```
\begin{array}{c|rrrr}
2 & 2 & -4 & -6 & 12 \\
+ & & 4 & 0 & -12 \\
\hline
& 2 & 0 & -6 & 0\\
\end{array}
```